# ng2-charts: Data updating, but not labels

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-charts

I created a component that uses Angular ChartJs charts and offers a function to update the data and labels. This works for the data, but not the labels for some reason.

### Component:

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Input,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';

@Component({
  selector: 'chart',
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective, { static: true }) chart: BaseChartDirective;
  @Input() type;
  @Input() title = '';
  labels = [];           // labels
  datasets = [{
    label: '',
    data: [],            // data
    hoverOffset: 4
  }
  ];
  options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      display: true,
      labels: {
        align: 'end',
        position: 'right'
      }
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: this.title,
      align: 'end',
      font: {
        size: 30
      }
    }
  };

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.options.title.text = this.title;
  }

  public updateData(labels: string[], data: number[]) {
  // Updates the data and labels.

    this.labels = labels;

    this.datasets[0].data = data;

    this.chart.update();
  }
}
```

### Template:

```
<div class="chart-container">
    <canvas #baseChart baseChart id="chart" [(datasets)]="datasets" [(labels)]="labels"
        [options]="options" [chartType]="type">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

If I use the component in another module and call the function, the data gets updated, but not the labels. They stay undefined.

### Chart when setting labels and data in `ngOnInit()`:

[image: with ngoninit]

### Chart when calling function to update data (note the incorrect labels):

[image: with update data function call]

### Labels and data values to be set:

[image]

If I set the labels within `ngOnInit()`, they are set correctly.

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: `this.chart.ngOnChanges({});`  add this after update() method

Comment: Thanks. This causes the error `TypeError: labels.slice is not a function`. I will investigate further.

Comment: Ok, I made it work. If you want, you can post this as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: What did you change to work this ?

Comment: Instead of directly assigning `this.labels = labels` in the update function, I had to assign it to `this.chart.labels = labels`, and then call `this.chart.ngOnChanges({})`.

Sorry for answering late, I was not sure what change exactly made it work and I had to check again. ng-charts can be weird sometimes.

Comment: Good! If you don't mind , I am looking for to work in angular. If you have any then it would be more helpful to me. Thank You. You can connect with me by this email id `grdtechlab@gmail.com`  Mean-while if you want then you can support me by https://www.buymeacoffee.com/grdtech